# Appending new results to an open jQuery autocomplete menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I have an app in which I have multiple search sources. Previously, the users had to choose in what source to search in before searching. If they did not choose, the app would default to one of the options.

However, now they want to search in all the sources at the same time. This is fine enough, but the problem is that when one of the searches returns, it overwrites the previous search result. Pretty much expected behavior. What I basically want is to append the new results to the already open autocomplete menu, instead of overwriting the old results. Naturally, the autocomplete menu would have to empty when it closes.

I guess that this is possible to do, but what approach is the best? I could just have an array I guess, which I append results to and then overwrite _renderMenu to use this array instead of the items one that is passed to the function. Then empty said array at the close event.

Is this the best way to go though? Or is there a more elegant solution?

Some code:
Ok, so searchAction is called by jquery autocomplete eventually. In collection.search I do the ajax call, here the URL is created based in the *this* parameter, then respondWhithData is called and maps the search result to a proper format (ie value and label for the autocomplete menu). After reponse is called from respondWithData, jquery automagically renders the resultsmenu. Thus, I probably have to overwrite the reponse event function as well as the _renderMenu and possibly _renderItem, yes?

```
searchAction: function(searchTerm, collection, response){
    var self = this;
    $.when(collection.search(searchTerm, this)).then(function(data) {
        self.respondWithData(data, response);
    });
},
respondWithData : function(data, response) {
    if (data.length > 0) {
        var responseVal = _.map(data, this.mapData);
        this.checkResponseCount(responseVal);
        response(responseVal);
    }
    else {
        response(this.emptyResult());
    }
},
```

To be clear, the problem is not the multiple search itself, but rendering the asynchronos results. I want to render the first results that come back, and then appends the rest as soon as they are returned from the server.

Edit 2: 
Just tried to edit ui.content in the autocompleteresponse event, but any edit does not take once it renders for some reason...

Edit 3: Ah, ui.content can only be modified directly, not changed. If I push every single change instead of concating two arrays ui.content shows what I want. 
It works I guess, but its not perfect.

Comment: Please add some code for the search post back

Comment: Done, but Im not exactly sure how it helps :)

Comment: Can you tell us which jQuery Autocomplete plugin you're using ? There's plenty of Autocomplete plugins out there.

Comment: Its from jQuery UI - v1.10.3

Answer (score 0):

I can figure how looks your scenario but I'm guessing:

You should have like:

```
function search1() {
   $.ajax({ ...
      success: function(data) {
         $('#myResultsDiv").html(data)
      }
   });    
}
```

etc

Instead of overwritting the #myResultsDiv you need to Append the results like:

```
function search1() {
   $.ajax({ ...
      success: function(data) {
         $('#myResultsDiv").append(data)
      }
   });    
}
```

Edit: You can also do something like this:

var resultsArray = [];
var searchDone = 0; 
var totalSearchs = 5; //assuming 5 searches

function search1() {

```
function search1() {
   $.ajax({ ...
      success: function(data) {
         //APPEND data to resultsArray
         searchDone++;
         if(searchDone==totalSearch) //syncronize the 5 searchs before render
            renderSearchs(resultsArray);

      }
   });    
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to sync all the searches for obvious reasons, ie users would have to wait longer, what if one fails, etc. 
The searches all go through the same ajax call, but with different URLs. Your solution does not really help me with autocomplete though, as stuff happens after the success callback. Ie, autocomplete calls its reponse function, as well as rendermenu and item.